# Spirit-Qi: How can I write a nonterminal parser?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I want to write a parser (as a qi extension) which can be used
via `my_parser(p1, p2, ...)` where `p1, p2, ...` are qi parser expressions.

Actually, I want to implement a `best_match`parser which works like qi alternative, but selects not the first matching rule but the rule which 'explains' most of the input.

Given two rules `simple_id = +(qi::alpha)` and `complex_id = simple_id >> *(qi::string("::") > simple_id)` it would select `complex_id` on the input `willy::anton`. And it would not produce intermediate attributes while doing so. These benefits get payed for with runtime because lookahead parsing is required.

In my view there are several use cases for such a parser construct. `benchmark(p1, ...)` as a supporting parser for optimization, just one example. I will provide that, once I know how to that.

This parser would be an non-terminal. I tried (hard), but I can not find answers to my problem within qi. My guess is, that C++ mechanisms are so tightly integrated withc qi, that there is no understandable entry point, at least for me.

It is quite easy to implement what I want introducing an operator. I append the current solution below. It compiles as expected but is incomplete.

A qi operator gets a fusion::vector/sequence (whatever) ready made and acts on it. There seem to be no library offerings to solve my problem. Even `make_nary_composite` already expects the args being compiled to `Elements`.

I tried a lot, everything failed, so I don't want to bore you with that.

A workaround which I can imagine could be to provide a stateful operator `,`, which would make `p1, ...` to a legal qi expression. Then implement a unary_parser `best_match` or directive to process that expression. 
The `,` would get two modes: getting the length of input the current (successful) parser consumes and actually parsing the selected one from phase 1. The wrapper what run that comma parser first in mode 1 and then in mode 2. It might be ugly, but could work.

The operator implementation `p1 |= p2 |= ...` is the most expensive regarding runtime for n > 2. I would be happy to get around that.

Minimum (but nevertheless reasonable) overhead would have `best_match(p1, ...)`.
Is that possible at all?

For I am not too experienced with boost::fusion I added some questions to the code as well (how tos regarding fusion).

It feels wrong, to press something which actually is a nary non-terminal parser into the unary parser scheme. But with my poor understanding it seems to be the only way to get it done. I'd highly appreciate any help to get me out of this.

My environment: Boost 1.61, MSVC 2015 Upd 2, target win32console.

PROGRESS:

I think, I'm getting it slowly but surely. I was very happy to see an `error_invalid_expression`. Compile failed because of the following proto expression:

```
boost::proto::exprns_::expr<
    boost::proto::tagns_::tag::function,boost::proto::argsns_::list5<
        const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<
            boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<
                mxc::qitoo::tag::best_match
            >
        ,0> &
        ,const boost::spirit::qi::rule<
            iterator_type,std::string (void),
            boost::spirit::standard::space_type,
            boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type> &
        ,const boost::spirit::qi::rule<
            iterator_type,std::string (void),
            boost::spirit::standard::space_type,
            boost::spirit::unused_type,
            boost::spirit::unused_type> &
        , const boost::spirit::qi::rule<
            iterator_type,std::string (void),
            boost::spirit::standard::space_type,
            boost::spirit::unused_type,
            boost::spirit::unused_type> &
        ,const boost::spirit::qi::rule<
            iterator_type,std::string (void),
            boost::spirit::standard::space_type,
            boost::spirit::unused_type,
            boost::spirit::unused_type> &
        >
    ,5>
```

This actually is the expression which describes my function-style usage of my best_match parser. My test rule looks like

```
qitoo::best_match(id, qualified_id, id, qualified_id)
```

where `id` and `qualified_id` are the rules as mentioned above. All that I want.
The error occurs because this expression does not have a member `parse`. Okay. Digging deeper I found qi's meta-compiler does support unary, binary and nary (what means variadic) parsers. But it does not support function style syntax. Qi seems to utilize unary, binary and nary for operators only. And allthough the nary type is supported, it is more or less obsolete, because qi operators are binary max.

END PROGRESS EDIT

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>

namespace boost {
    namespace spirit
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Enablers
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        template <>
        struct use_operator<qi::domain, proto::tag::bitwise_or_assign> // enables |=
            : mpl::true_ {};

        template <>
        struct flatten_tree<qi::domain, proto::tag::bitwise_or_assign> // flattens |=
            : mpl::true_ {};
    }
}

namespace mxc {
    namespace qitoo {

        namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
        namespace qi = spirit::qi;
        namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

        template <typename Elements>
        struct best_match_parser : qi::nary_parser<mxc::qitoo::best_match_parser<Elements>>
        {
            // This one does a lookahead parse of each qi expression to find out which rule matches 
            // most of the input 
            template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename Skipper>
            struct best_function
            {
                best_function(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last, Context& context,
                    Skipper const& skipper, int& best, int& idx, int& size)
                    : first(first), last(last), context(context), skipper(skipper), best(best),
                    idx(idx), size(size) {};

                template <typename Component>
                void operator()(Component& component) const
                {
                    Iterator f = first;
                    if (component.parse(f, last, context, skipper, qi::unused)) {
                        // please have a look on how I transport best, idx and size
                        // into the parser context
                        //
                        // I guess, this is a nasty hack and could be done better
                        // Any advice would be highliy appreciated

                        int l = f - first;
                        if (l > size) {
                            size = l;
                            best = idx++;
                        }
                        idx++;
                    }
                }

            private:
                int& best;
                int& idx;
                int& size;

                Iterator&       first;
                Iterator const& last;
                Context&        context;
                Skipper const&  skipper;
            };

            template <typename Context, typename Iterator>
            struct attribute
            {
                // Put all the element attributes in a tuple
                typedef typename spirit::traits::build_attribute_sequence <
                    Elements, Context, spirit::traits::alternative_attribute_transform
                    , Iterator, qi::domain
                >::type all_attributes;

                // Ok, now make a variant over the attribute sequence. Note that
                // build_variant makes sure that 1) all attributes in the variant
                // are unique 2) puts the unused attribute, if there is any, to
                // the front and 3) collapses single element variants, variant<T>
                // to T.
                typedef typename
                    spirit::traits::build_variant<all_attributes>::type
                    type;
            };

            best_match_parser(Elements const& elements_) : elements(elements_), size(0), idx(0), best(-1) {}


            template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename Skipper, typename Attribute>
            bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last
                , Context& context, Skipper const& skipper
                , Attribute& attr_) const
            {
                best_function<Iterator, Context, Skipper>  f(first, last, context, skipper, best, idx, size);

                // find out which parser matches most of the input
                fusion::for_each(elements, f);

                // best >= 0 if at least one parser was successful
                if (best >= 0) {
                    // now that I have the best parser identified, how do I access it?
                    // I understand that the next line can not work, but I'm looking for something like that

                    // --> auto v = fusion::at<boost::mpl::int_<best>>(elements);
                };

                return false;
            }

            template <typename Context>
            qi::info what(Context& context) const
            {
                qi::info result("best_match");
                fusion::for_each(elements,
                    spirit::detail::what_function<Context>(result, context));

                return result;
            }

            Elements elements;
            mutable int  best;
            mutable int  idx;
            mutable int  size;

        };
    }
}

namespace boost {
    namespace spirit {
        namespace qi {

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Parser generators: make_xxx function (objects)
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            template <typename Elements, typename Modifiers>
            struct make_composite<proto::tag::bitwise_or_assign, Elements, Modifiers>
                : make_nary_composite < Elements, mxc::qitoo::best_match_parser >
            {};
        }

        namespace traits {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            template <typename Elements>
            struct has_semantic_action<mxc::qitoo::best_match_parser<Elements> >
                : nary_has_semantic_action<Elements> {};

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            template <typename Elements, typename Attribute, typename Context
                , typename Iterator>
                struct handles_container<mxc::qitoo::best_match_parser<Elements>, Attribute, Context
                , Iterator>
                : nary_handles_container<Elements, Attribute, Context, Iterator> {};
        }
    }
}
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace qitoo = mxc::qitoo;

using iterator_type = std::string::const_iterator;
using result_type = std::string;

template<typename Parser>
void parse(const std::string message, const std::string& input, const std::string& rule, const Parser& parser) {
    iterator_type iter = input.begin(), end = input.end();

    std::vector<result_type> parsed_result;

    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    std::cout << message << "\n";
    std::cout << "Rule: " << rule << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Parsing: \"" << input << "\"\n";

    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, qi::space, parsed_result);
    if (result)
    {
        std::cout << "Parser succeeded.\n";
        std::cout << "Parsed " << parsed_result.size() << " elements:";
        for (const auto& str : parsed_result)
            std::cout << "[" << str << "]";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Parser failed" << std::endl;
    }
    if (iter == end) {
        std::cout << "EOI reached." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "EOI not reached. Unparsed: \"" << std::string(iter, end) << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";

}


int main()
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    qi::rule < iterator_type, std::string(), qi::space_type>
        id = (qi::alpha | qi::char_('_')) >> *(qi::alnum | qi::char_('_'));

    qi::rule < iterator_type, std::string(), qi::space_type>
        qualified_id = id >> *(qi::string("::") > id);


    namespace qitoo = mxc::qitoo;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    parse("best match operator, select second rule"
        , "willy::anton::lutz"
        , "id |= qualified_id"
        , id |= qualified_id);
}
```

Comment: Found a solution but that involved modifying the meta-compiler and make_component part of qi. If there are other solutions I did not manage to find out. I am not too happy with my non-standard qi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Your example

I don't see how your sample requires any of this. Just reorder your branches, then realize that the short branch is just a special case of the qualified case with n=1: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1191dadc88b9cea1)¹ (or [using X3 version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f80074001bf8c39) if you prefer).

### The generic case

Now, having mentioned x3, it has the capacity to make your live much easier!

Here's what I think you wanted, in the general case:

```
namespace parser {

    template <typename... Parsers>
    struct longest_parser : x3::parser_base {
        longest_parser(Parsers... sub) : _alternatives {sub...} { }

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename Other, typename Attr>
        bool parse(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, Other const& other, Attr& attr) const {
            auto const saved = f;

            //// To exclude pre-skip from length comparisons, do pre-skip here:
            // x3::skip_over(f, l, ctx);
            auto seq = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Parsers)>();

            auto best = select_best(f, l, ctx, seq);
            //std::cout << "Longest match at index #" << best << "\n";

            bool ok = dispatch(f, l, ctx, other, attr, best, seq);

            if (!ok)
                f = saved;

            return ok;
        }

      private:
        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename P>
        size_t length_of(It f, It l, Ctx ctx, P const& p) const {
            boost::iterator_range<It> matched;
            return x3::raw[p].parse(f, l, ctx, x3::unused, matched)? boost::size(matched) : 0;
        }

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, size_t... I>
            size_t select_best(It f, It l, Ctx& ctx, std::index_sequence<I...>) const {
                std::array<size_t, sizeof...(I)> lengths { length_of(f, l, ctx, std::get<I>(_alternatives))... };
                return std::distance(lengths.begin(), std::max_element(lengths.begin(), lengths.end()));
            }

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename Other, typename Attr, size_t... I>
        bool dispatch(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, Other const& other, Attr& attr, size_t targetIdx, std::index_sequence<I...>) const {
            //return (real_parse<I>(f, l, ctx, other, attr, targetIdx) || ...);
            std::array<bool, sizeof...(I)> b = { real_parse<I>(f, l, ctx, other, attr, targetIdx)... };

            return std::accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), false, std::logical_or<bool>());
        }

        template <size_t Idx, typename It, typename Ctx, typename Other, typename Attr>
        bool real_parse(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, Other const& other, Attr& attr, size_t targetIdx) const {
            if (targetIdx != Idx)
                return false;

            return std::get<Idx>(_alternatives).parse(f, l, ctx, other, attr);
        }

        std::tuple<Parsers...> _alternatives;
    };

    template <typename... Ps>
        longest_parser<Ps...> longest(Ps... p) { return {x3::as_parser(p)...}; }
}
```

Note the fold expression you could use in `dispatch` if your compiler supports it (Coliru does, [edit it to see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/917588032326aa18)!).

> *Note also the subtle choice regarding skippable (probably whitespace); if it's not significant for the length comparisons, uncomment the pre-skip.*

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb13c1d357cdc464)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace std {
    template <typename T> // just for easy debug printing; hack
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v) {
        for (auto& el : v) std::cout << '[' << el << ']';
        return os;
    }
}

using string_vec  = std::vector<std::string>;
using result_type = boost::variant<std::string, double, string_vec>;

template <typename Parser>
void parse(const std::string message, const std::string &input, const std::string &rule, const Parser &parser) {
    auto iter = input.begin(), end = input.end();

    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    std::cout << message << "\n";
    std::cout << "Rule:     " << rule  << "\n";
    std::cout << "Parsing: '" << input << "'\n";

    result_type parsed_result;
    bool result = phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, x3::space, parsed_result);

    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << parsed_result << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parser failed\n";
    }
    if (iter != end)
        std::cout << "EOI not reached. Unparsed: '" << std::string(iter, end) << "'\n";
}

namespace parser {

    template <typename... Parsers>
    struct longest_parser : x3::parser_base {
        longest_parser(Parsers... sub) : _alternatives {sub...} { }

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename Other, typename Attr>
        bool parse(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, Other const& other, Attr& attr) const {
            auto const saved = f;

            //// To exclude pre-skip from length comparisons, do pre-skip here:
            // x3::skip_over(f, l, ctx);
            auto seq = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Parsers)>();

            auto best = select_best(f, l, ctx, seq);
            //std::cout << "Longest match at index #" << best << "\n";

            bool ok = dispatch(f, l, ctx, other, attr, best, seq);

            if (!ok)
                f = saved;

            return ok;
        }

      private:
        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename P>
        size_t length_of(It f, It l, Ctx ctx, P const& p) const {
            boost::iterator_range<It> matched;
            return x3::raw[p].parse(f, l, ctx, x3::unused, matched)? boost::size(matched) : 0;
        }

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, size_t... I>
            size_t select_best(It f, It l, Ctx& ctx, std::index_sequence<I...>) const {
                std::array<size_t, sizeof...(I)> lengths { length_of(f, l, ctx, std::get<I>(_alternatives))... };
                return std::distance(lengths.begin(), std::max_element(lengths.begin(), lengths.end()));
            }

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename Other, typename Attr, size_t... I>
        bool dispatch(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, Other const& other, Attr& attr, size_t targetIdx, std::index_sequence<I...>) const {
            //return (real_parse<I>(f, l, ctx, other, attr, targetIdx) || ...);
            std::array<bool, sizeof...(I)> b = { real_parse<I>(f, l, ctx, other, attr, targetIdx)... };

            return std::accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), false, std::logical_or<bool>());
        }

        template <size_t Idx, typename It, typename Ctx, typename Other, typename Attr>
        bool real_parse(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, Other const& other, Attr& attr, size_t targetIdx) const {
            if (targetIdx != Idx)
                return false;

            return std::get<Idx>(_alternatives).parse(f, l, ctx, other, attr);
        }

        std::tuple<Parsers...> _alternatives;
    };

    template <typename... Ps>
        longest_parser<Ps...> longest(Ps... p) { return {x3::as_parser(p)...}; }
}

int main() {
    auto id        = x3::rule<void, std::string> {} = x3::lexeme [ x3::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *x3::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_") ];
    auto qualified = x3::rule<void, string_vec>  {} = id % "::";

#define TEST_CASE(label, input, rule) parse(label, input, #rule, rule)
    TEST_CASE("unqualified"                , "willy"                , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_));
    TEST_CASE("unqualified with whitespace", " willy \t"            , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_));
    TEST_CASE("integral or number"         , "123.78::anton::lutz"  , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_));
    TEST_CASE("qualified"                  , "willy anton::lutz"    , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_));
    TEST_CASE("qualified with whitespace"  , "willy \tanton::lutz"  , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_));

    TEST_CASE("unqualified"                , "willy"                , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("unqualified with whitespace", " willy \t"            , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("integral or number"         , "123.78::anton::lutz"  , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("qualified"                  , "willy::anton::lutz"   , parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("qualified with whitespace"  , "willy ::\tanton::lutz", parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));

    TEST_CASE("unqualified"                , "willy"                , parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("unqualified with whitespace", " willy \t"            , parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("integral or number"         , "123.78::anton::lutz"  , parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("qualified"                  , "willy::anton::lutz"   , parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
    TEST_CASE("qualified with whitespace"  , "willy ::\tanton::lutz", parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified));
}
```

Prints

```
-------------------------
unqualified
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_)
Parsing: 'willy'
Parsed willy
-------------------------
unqualified with whitespace
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_)
Parsing: ' willy    '
Parsed willy
-------------------------
integral or number
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_)
Parsing: '123.78::anton::lutz'
Parsed 123.78
EOI not reached. Unparsed: '::anton::lutz'
-------------------------
qualified
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_)
Parsing: 'willy anton::lutz'
Parsed willy
EOI not reached. Unparsed: 'anton::lutz'
-------------------------
qualified with whitespace
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_)
Parsing: 'willy     anton::lutz'
Parsed willy
EOI not reached. Unparsed: 'anton::lutz'
-------------------------
unqualified
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: 'willy'
Parsed willy
-------------------------
unqualified with whitespace
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: ' willy    '
Parsed willy
-------------------------
integral or number
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: '123.78::anton::lutz'
Parsed 123.78
EOI not reached. Unparsed: '::anton::lutz'
-------------------------
qualified
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: 'willy::anton::lutz'
Parsed [willy][anton][lutz]
-------------------------
qualified with whitespace
Rule:     parser::longest(id, x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: 'willy ::  anton::lutz'
Parsed [willy][anton][lutz]
-------------------------
unqualified
Rule:     parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: 'willy'
Parsed [willy]
-------------------------
unqualified with whitespace
Rule:     parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: ' willy    '
Parsed [willy]
-------------------------
integral or number
Rule:     parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: '123.78::anton::lutz'
Parsed 123.78
EOI not reached. Unparsed: '::anton::lutz'
-------------------------
qualified
Rule:     parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: 'willy::anton::lutz'
Parsed [willy][anton][lutz]
-------------------------
qualified with whitespace
Rule:     parser::longest(x3::int_, x3::double_, qualified)
Parsing: 'willy ::  anton::lutz'
Parsed [willy][anton][lutz]
```

Note the different results depending on the parser expressions in the alternatives.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Yes, I know, X3 makes live much easier. Have been investigating that a bit. But qi 2 for me is kind of a masterpiece of sophisticated metaprogramming for a particular problem domain. I need a problem domain for motivation. I'd never learn metaprogramming just because I could. ;) So, before I take the deep dive into the 'ease of auto' with X3, I go into the qi 2 detail. And, X3 is not stable yet, so it is not an opportunity for our customers who don't want to be at the 'bleeding edge'. ;) Anyway, I tried to create an example to motivate the idea. Obviously was not the best one.

Comment: Sounds like awesome plan. Good luck!

Comment: I scribbled down some of my findings here, leaving out that 'modifying the qi core' part. I do not want just to ask silly questions to steal people's time. See [MxcQitoo on GitHub](https://github.com/mxc-commons/MxcQitoo). And here on the [mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/spirit/mailman/message/35157116/).

Comment: The better question would have been: How do I implement a parser component which acts as an operator of arbitrary arity?

Comment: I created a pull request for qi to enable support of n-ary operators using function style syntax. Joel likes the implementation, but asked me to bring community oppinions to that. You are one of the few with very deep knowledge about qi and X3. May I ask you to assess https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/pull/200? Is it valuable?