# How to rewrite qi parsers with inherited attributes in x3?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-x3

If the inherited attributes are used in semantic actions, we can use `x3::with` directive.

What if we want to use the attributes as part of the parser? For example a simple parser matches 1 or more alphabet characters except the character is from a parameter char set.

```
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, qi::unused_type(char const*)> rule =
    +(qi::alpha - qi::char_(qi::_r1));
```

Or the parameter char set could be used as a lazy parser.

```
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, qi::unused_type(char const*)> rule =
    +(qi::alpha - qi::lazy(qi::_r1));
```

x3::with directive put this local value in the context. I'm not sure if we could use this context outside a semantic action and eventually generate a parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply let go of the old habit of rule-ifying everything.

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename... Args>
auto negate(Args&&... p) {
    return +(x3::char_ - x3::char_(std::forward<Args>(p)...));
};

int main() {
    std::string input("all the king's men and all the king's horses"), parsed;
    if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), negate("horse"), parsed))
        std::cout << "'" << input << "' -> '" << parsed << "'\n";
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc3179146360ae7e)</kbd>**, prints:

`'all the king's men and all the king's horses' -> 'all t'`

Second flavour:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename Sub>
auto negate(Sub p) {
    return +(x3::char_ - x3::as_parser(p));
};

int main() {
    std::string input("all the king's men and all the king's horses"), parsed;
    if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), negate("horse"), parsed))
        std::cout << "'" << input << "' -> '" << parsed << "'\n";
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb4fabf0ce6d1f33)</kbd>**, prints:

`'all the king's men and all the king's horses' -> 'all the king's men and all the king's '`

### More complicated stuff

You can also aggregate sub parsers in a custom parser:

- [Spirit-Qi: How can I write a nonterminal parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669936/spirit-qi-how-can-i-write-a-nonterminal-parser/37823837#37823837)

If you need resursive rules with passing around, I'd suggest `x3::with<>` (although I'm not sure the contexts build re-entrant state for the `with<>`, you need to test the precise semantics unless you can find documentation for it)